# multidimensional array php - sum values with same groupRange

Tags: php, arrays, symfony, multidimensional-array

I will try to explain my problem in small examples:
I have a multidimensional array that represents data from the database, lets's say the input looks like this:

```
Array
(
[0] => Array
(
[groupRange] => 20-25
[value] => 12
[followersFemaleRate] => 12
[followersMaleRate] => 14
)

[1] => Array
(
[groupRange] => 30-44
[value] => 32
[followersFemaleRate] => 17
[followersMaleRate] => 3
)

[2] => Array
(
[groupRange] => 30-44
[value] => 88
[followersFemaleRate] => 17
[followersMaleRate] => 3
)

)
```

What I want? To sum value, followersFemaleRate, followersMaleRate with the same groupRange, so the output should be this:

```
Array
(
[0] => Array
(
[groupRange] => 20-25
[value] => 12
[followersFemaleRate] => 12
[followersMaleRate] => 14
)

[1] => Array
(
[groupRange] => 30-44
[value] => 120
[followersFemaleRate] => 34
[followersMaleRate] => 6
)

)
```

My code:

```
    $RangeArray = [];
    foreach($dbProfile->getData() as $d) {
        foreach ($d->getGroupPercentages() as $x){
            $ageRangeSingleArray['groupRange'] = $x->getGroupRange();
            $ageRangeSingleArray['value'] = $x->getValue();
            $ageRangeSingleArray['followersFemaleRate'] = $x->getFollowerGenderFemale();
            $ageRangeSingleArray['followersMaleRate'] = $x->getFollowerGenderMale();
            $RangeArray [] = $ageRangeSingleArray;
        }
    }
```

However im stuck, my idea is to first check if groupRage already exists, if yes, sum values for that range, if not add new element groupRange with values, any help with code?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

try:

```
$input = [
    [
        'groupRange' => '20-25',
        'value' => 12,
        'followersFemaleRate' => 12,
        'followersMaleRate' => 14,
    ],
    [
        'groupRange' => '30-44',
        'value' => 88,
        'followersFemaleRate' => 17,
        'followersMaleRate' => 3,
    ],
    [
        'groupRange' => '30-44',
        'value' => 32,
        'followersFemaleRate' => 17,
        'followersMaleRate' => 3,
    ],
];

$groupedArray = [];             
foreach( $input as $item ){
    $groupedArray[$item['groupRange']]['groupRange'] = $item['groupRange'];
    $groupedArray[$item['groupRange']]['value'] = ($groupedArray[$item['groupRange']]['value'] ?? 0) + $item['value'];
    $groupedArray[$item['groupRange']]['followersFemaleRate'] = $item['followersFemaleRate'];
    $groupedArray[$item['groupRange']]['followersMaleRate'] = $item['followersMaleRate'];
}

$output = array_values($groupedArray);

print_r($output);
```

output:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [groupRange] => 20-25
            [value] => 12
            [followersFemaleRate] => 12
            [followersMaleRate] => 14
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [groupRange] => 30-44
            [value] => 120
            [followersFemaleRate] => 17
            [followersMaleRate] => 3
        )

)
```

Answer (score 0):

@Salines solution was good, but I offer a simple solution for the beginners...

Another simple solution to your problem:

```php
$input = [
    [
        'groupRange' => '20-25',
        'value' => 12,
        'followersFemaleRate' => 12,
        'followersMaleRate' => 14,
    ],
    [
        'groupRange' => '30-44',
        'value' => 88,
        'followersFemaleRate' => 17,
        'followersMaleRate' => 3,
    ],
    [
        'groupRange' => '30-44',
        'value' => 32,
        'followersFemaleRate' => 17,
        'followersMaleRate' => 3,
    ],
];

$groupRangeHolder = [];
$output = [];


foreach($input as $item) {

    if( ! array_key_exists( $item['groupRange'] , $groupRangeHolder ) )
    {
        $groupRangeHolder[$item['groupRange']]['value'] = $item['value'];
        $groupRangeHolder[$item['groupRange']]['followersFemaleRate'] = $item['followersFemaleRate'];
        $groupRangeHolder[$item['groupRange']]['followersMaleRate'] = $item['followersMaleRate'];
    }
    else
    {
        $groupRangeHolder[$item['groupRange']]['value'] += $item['value'];
        $groupRangeHolder[$item['groupRange']]['followersFemaleRate'] += $item['followersFemaleRate'];
        $groupRangeHolder[$item['groupRange']]['followersMaleRate'] += $item['followersMaleRate'];
    }

}


$cur = 0;
foreach($groupRangeHolder as $key => $values) 
{
    $output[$cur]['groupRange'] = $key;
    $output[$cur]['value'] = $values['value'];
    $output[$cur]['followersFemaleRate'] = $values['followersFemaleRate'];
    $output[$cur++]['followersMaleRate'] = $values['followersMaleRate'];
}


echo "<pre>";
print_r($output);
echo "</pre>";
```